# Discord.net -- Discord Username to SocketGuildUser

Tags: discord.net

How do I change a Discord Username: Example####
To a SocketGuildPlayer so I can send a message to a Specific user?

Comment: Would you like to respond to his message he send on the server? If yes you can do -> Context.User.SendMessageAsync("");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple to do :

```
var x = (Context.Client.GetUser("username", "discrim") as SocketGuildUser);
```

`Context.Client` is of type `DiscordSocketClient`.

Answer (score 0):

With little context, there is little I can suggest.

Use LinQ (e.g.)

`SocketGuild.Users.where( x => x.Username == "Example" )
                  .where( x => x.Discriminator == "####")`
to get the `SocketGuildUser` from the `SocketGuild` object.